# Does changing an answer to CW count as editing the answer?

Tags: support, community-wiki

If a user changes his/her answers to CW, is this counted as editing the answers?

Does it then have the same limitation consecutive post edit has?
If, as moderator, I see a flag about a possible vandalism of own posts, does that mean the user effectively edited the content of the posts, or is that raised also when a user start changing his/her answers to CW?

Comment: Only one way to find out...

Comment: why don't you check the post to see if it has been edited? 5 posts isn't all that hard, and drupal isn't SO...

Comment: @Shog9 The only site where I can see if I am flagged for possible vandalism is the one where I am moderator. Do moderators get flagged for possible vandalism?

Comment: Only one way to find out...

Comment: @Shog9: So... There must be someone there at SE that still knows how to read code, no?

Comment: @Robert: You'd trust *code* for something like this? Pfft. It's all super-intelligent hamsters man!